# Mysql query runs perfectly but JPA query returns nothing

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am trying to get this query to work in JPA

It works perfectly in mysql:

```
select * from order_header join order_detail where (order_header.buying_partner_id = 1 or order_header.buying_partner_id = 3) AND ((order_detail.warehouse_id = 6) or (order_header.warehouse_id = 6 and order_detail.warehouse_id is null ) ) and (order_detail.tracking_number is null or order_detail.tracking_number = '') and order_detail.canceled != 1 and (order_header.order_num is NOT NULL and order_header.order_num != '') and order_header.timestamp > '2017-01-24 08:33:00.096' group by order_header.order_num order by order_header.comment DESC;
```

Results are returned.

JPA Query:

```
Select h FROM OrderHeader h JOIN h.orderDetails d WHERE  ( h.buyingPartner.id = 1 or h.buyingPartner.id = 3 ) AND  (    (d.warehouse.id =6)         OR     ( h.warehouse.id =6  AND d.warehouse.id IS null  )   )     AND (d.trackingNumber IS null or d.trackingNumber = '')     AND  d.canceled != 1 AND (h.orderNum IS NOT null AND h.orderNum != '') and h.timestamp > '2017-01-24 09:32:39.865'  GROUP BY h.orderNum ORDER BY h.comment DESC
```

It returns nothing. No errors. Just returns nothing.

These are the exact same statements.

There must be something wrong with my JPA statement.

Comment: Well i see lots of differences `order_header`  vs `OrderHeader`... `order_detail` vs orderDetails... looks to me they are not the same statements....

Answer (score 0):

```
Select h FROM OrderHeader h JOIN h.orderDetails d WHERE ( h.buyingPartner.id = 1 or h.buyingPartner.id = 3 ) AND ( (d.warehouse.id =6) OR ( h.warehouse.id =6 AND d.warehouse.id IS null ) ) AND (d.trackingNumber IS null or d.trackingNumber = '') AND d.canceled != 1 AND (h.orderNum IS NOT null AND h.orderNum != '') and h.timestamp > '2017-01-24 09:32:39.865' GROUP BY h.orderNum ORDER BY h.comment DESC
```

Comment: Select h  rather than select *

Comment: May I know if the difference between ur timestamp in the query causing the problem?

Comment: if you remove the timestamp nothing changes.

Comment: Can u show us the OrderHeader and orderDetails entity object?

Comment: I am thinking if h.buyingPartner.id should be h.buyingPartnerId and d.warehouse.id should be d.warehouseId

Comment: nope it crashes if i do that since id is in buyerPartner and warehouse class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136564/discussion-between-user1863457-and-katrin).

Answer (score 0):

JPA Query uses the `JOIN` condition when you created the relationship between entities.

For raw SQL query you have not provided that `ON` condition which will be included default in JPA Query.

That's the only difference I see in it.